# iOS 7 And iOS 6 Different Versions Of The Same App

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

I have an iphone app that was accepted in the App Store before the arrival of iOS 7. The app used to support both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Now i have updated the same app to iOS 7 and about to submit it to the App Store for approval. I have a question that is making me confuse.

**Question 1:** Is there any way the first version of the app stays in the App Store for iOS 5 and iOS 6 users while the new version that i am going to submit only serves the iOS 7 users. In other words, i want to save some time but not updating the same app compatible with the old versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since a few weeks. If a customer downloads your app and it is not available for his device (e.g. the app is iOS 7 only and the customer has iOS 6) **and** there is a < iOS 7 supporting version uploaded earlier, it will download that one.

Source: **[Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/17/apple-ios-last-compatible-version-app-iphone-ipod-ipad/)**

Comment: oo thats exactly what i was looking for. Shall i just submit the new version of the app with supported version to 7.0?

Comment: Yes, just submit an update with only iOS 7 support. Keep in mind that if you don't support previous iOS versions you will exclude them from new features = possibly bad ratings.

Comment: I am very skeptical about the article this is linked too. Apple have never done this in the past and there is nothing from Apple themselves about his ever.

Comment: @Popeye I have seen this notification many times when downloading from the App Store on my iOS 6 debugging device.

Comment: I have never seen this and I have just tried downloading the app that article says to download and I never got that message. Like I say this hasn't been documented anywhere by Apple and their iOS 7 UI Transition Guide gives clear instructions on how to support iOS 7 and iOS 6 and this is not in there at all, it actually has what will happen if you decide against continuing support for iOS 6, and that is the exact same thing that has happen in the past it will not allow you. So if this is happening for you I would report this to Apple as a bug as according to their documentation this shouldn't

Comment: Also I have two apps that only support `iOS 7` and not `iOS 6` and they once did support it and I don't get this when trying to download my apps. I think you need to support this answer with Apple Documentation.

Comment: Documentation is here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5919. This is valid ONLY for previous users of the app. If the user already has the app associated with his/her Apple ID, and goes to redownload the app (e.g.: through the Purchased tab of the App Store application), he/she is given the possibility of downloading the last compatible version. So it does NOT work for new users trying to download/buy your app.

Answer (score 6):

A user that has an iOS version prior to 7.0 and have previously downloaded you app, can still restore the old version from iCloud.

New users of your app can not download an old version.

This is the information Apple sent out regarding this:

"Users who have already purchased your app are now able to download previous versions, allowing them to use your app with older devices that may no longer be supported by the current version.

If you do not want previous versions of your app to be available, for example due to a usability or legal issue, you can manage their availability in the Rights and Pricing section of the Manage Your Apps module on iTunes Connect."

Answer (score 1):

- First off I am going to ask why?
- Secondly the two answers already given are completely wrong.

  - Too `yoeriboven`s answer this isn't true, Apple haven't confirmed this and it isn't documented anywhere in the Apple documentation. The best reply I have for that article is it is complete rubbish. Unless Apple have confirmed it, it isn't true.
  - To `user1673099`s answer this is also not a good why to go. This means two apps to maintain on the app store, so unless one is a LITE version and the other is a FULL version I just wouldn't go this way at all.

The one thing I am going to do which is the actual way you should be working if you want to support `iOS 5`, `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` is direct you to the [Official Apple Documentation for Supporting iOS 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html).

This guide will help you make the transition from `iOS 6` to `iOS 7` and it will also instructed you on how to completely support previous `iOS` versions.

You might also want to read [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide Before You Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/) and [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide Scoping Your Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Scoping.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH7-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

I ask same question on Apple Support Communities. It is possible. They replied this-

iOS 7 and OS X Mavericks include new features that many of your favorite apps take advantage of when you update them. Some of these features are specific to the latest versions of iOS and OS X. As a result, the latest versions of some apps may not work with your device or computer if you are still using an earlier version of iOS or OS X. Thanks to the App Store, you may still be able to re-download a compatible, earlier version of an app when you are using an older operating system.

Here's how you install an earlier version of an app:

```
Open the App Store (with iOS 4.3.3 or later) or Mac App Store (with OS X Mountain Lion).
Go to the Purchased screen (iOS) or Purchases tab (OS X).
Select the app you want to download.
```

If a compatible version of the app is available for your version of iOS or OS X, simply confirm that you want to download it. For example, after purchasing iPhoto for your iOS 7 device, you can install an earlier compatible version of iPhoto from your iOS 6 device.
Additional Information

Note: Some earlier versions of apps may not be downloadable from the App Store if the app's developer has chosen not to make them available. If you don't see the version of the app you are looking for, contact the app developer for more information. The developer's contact information can be found on the app's product page on the App Store.

You can also read it from here-

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5919

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `different BundleId` for Ios 7 app & changed it `deployment target to ios 7.0`.

So, idea is that you are making two different apps.

1. ios<7.0
2. ios=7.0

May this helpful to you.